# Why can't consecutive irrational numbers be treated mathematically as limits?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinity

I'm a relative newcomer to these stackexchange websites, and this post will serve as my introduction to the **Mathematics** stackexchange site.
After perusing some of the related questions, I found these to be the most relevant to my question: 1) [Why can't you count real numbers this way?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528656/why-cant-you-count-real-numbers-this-way?rq=1), 2) [Why there is not the next real number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696043/why-there-is-not-the-next-real-number), 3) [Proof that the real numbers are countable: Help with why this is wrong](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61174/proof-that-the-real-numbers-are-countable-help-with-why-this-is-wrong?rq=1), and 4) [Why does the Dedekind Cut work well enough to define the Reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95271/why-does-the-dedekind-cut-work-well-enough-to-define-the-reals?rq=1) .

In related question #1), the concept of an "index" with regard to the un/countability of the set of real numbers was mentioned. I have encountered that term before in past discussions regarding the countability of transfinite **ordinal** sets (in other math forum websites), but I'm not sure what it means.

In any case, I understand the "real-number line" to be composed of the set of *rational* numbers (whose cardinality is $\aleph_0$) which have sets of "gaps" between them, each of which is filled in by a set of *irrational* numbers (whose cardinality is $\aleph_1$). My *"understanding"* is that there are no "gaps" between any two consecutive irrational numbers, and likewise, no "gaps" between a rational number and the irrational numbers that immediately precede and follow it. If all of this is true, then given some number $n$ (rational or irrational), why can't I write **the next consecutive irrational number that immediately follows n** as $\lim_{t\to\infty}n+10^{-t}$.

Comment: I think the reason is quite simply that the limit you pose is actually $n$ since you can make it arbitrarily close to $n$ as you like.

Comment: Between any two distinct real numbers there's an infinite number of rationals and an infinite number of irrationals, therefore, the phrase `My "understanding" is that there are no "gaps" between any two consecutive irrational numbers` is quite false.

Comment: Furthermore, there is no such thing as the irrational number that "precedes" or "follows" a rational number.  The real numbers are simply not organized in a sequence the way the integers are.

Comment: "I think the reason is quite simply that the limit you pose is actually n" True! But that is precisely *why* I'm seeking some way to represent irrational numbers. I would like to find a way to represent them that enables us to differentiate them from one another mathematically.

Comment: [My answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694150/enough-dedekind-cuts-to-define-all-irrationals/694196#694196) addresses several of your confusions, including your mistaken understanding of the $\lim$ notation.

Comment: Then try to read any introductory course on analysis with an explicit construction of a model of real numbers. One of my favorite is to represent reals as a set of converging sequences of rationals modulo the equivalence relation.

Comment: "The real numbers are simply not organized in a sequence the way the integers are ..." Really? Then why don't they simply merge into one another?

Comment: "..., including your mistaken understanding of the lim notation" Ok.

Comment: "Then try to read any introductory course on analysis with an explicit construction of a model of real numbers." You mean mathematical analysis, not real analysis, correct?

Answer (score 9):

You asked specifically

> why can't I write **the next consecutive irrational number that immediately follows n** as $\lim_{t\to\infty}n+10^{-t}$.

This $\lim_{t\to \infty}$ notation is a mathematical term of art; it has a specific meaning, and it simply doesn't mean what you think it does.  You have the idea that it means $n$ plus some tiny tiny number that is smaller than every other number.  But it doesn't mean that, because there is no such thing as a tiny tiny number that is smaller than every other number. What you have written is actually a complicated way of writing the number $n$, nothing more.

I sympathize with your desire to invent a tiny tiny number that is smaller than every other number, because it sounds plausible, and almost everyone tries to do it at some point. But  on closer investigation, the idea turns out to be incoherent, and this is why there is no notation for that tiny tiny number.

Consider this analogy: the phrase “the biggest purple hat in my closet” sounds reasonable, and there is no obvious reason why such a thing doesn't exist. But in fact there is no such thing as the biggest purple hat in my closet, although you have to know a bit about the contents of my closet to know this.  (I don't have any purple hats.)

Similarly, *there is no such thing* as the number that is the next bigger real number after $n$, although you have to know a little bit about real numbers to realize this.  For suppose there were such a number; let us call it $y$.  Then let $\epsilon = y - n$.  Since $y$ is bigger than $n$, the number $\epsilon$ is positive.   But then $\frac\epsilon2$ is positive also, although smaller than $\epsilon$, so we have $0 < \frac\epsilon2 < \epsilon$. Then adding $n$ to each part of that inequality, we get $$n < n+\frac\epsilon2 < n+\epsilon = y$$ which shows that $n+\frac\epsilon2$ is between $n$ and $y$, and therefore that $y$ was *not* the next number bigger than $n$.  But this argument works for *any* possible number $y$ that you could invent, so the whole idea of a number $y$ that is the next bigger number after $n$ has to be scrapped.

I'm not sure this answers your question, but your question is based on several basic (but very common) misunderstandings of how numbers work, so I hope this helps clear up some of it. But the question posed by the title of your question, “Why can't consecutive irrational numbers…” can be answered without even reading the whole thing; the answer is “because there is no such thing as consecutive irrational numbers.”

Comment: Yes, I follow your reasoning. I see that the way irrational numbers are structured (as a set) is fundamentally different (and not simply quantitatively different) from the way the rational numbers are structured.

Comment: For these purposes, the rationals and the irrationals are not very different.  Neither one is like the natural numbers, where there  *is*  a tiny tiny natural number smaller than every other natural number (we call this number “$1$”) and where there *is* a clear notion of "next bigger natural number". It might be instructive to see why, if you want $y$ to be the next bigger *natural number* after $n$, my argument above about the nonexistence of $y$ fails, as it must.

Comment: Well, your argument wouldn't apply in that case because the natural numbers are not closed with regard to division. (But it would still be valid where it *did* apply.) But, Yes, I do see your point. Your argument would also work for the rationals.

Comment: Yes, exactly so.  There are no consecutive rationals.

Comment: Ok. So what all of this seems to suggest to me is that between *any* two rational numbers on the "real-number line", there are aleph-one irrational numbers that each have aleph-one rational and irrational numbers between them, and so on. Would that be correct?

Comment: Close. Between any two rational numbers are $\aleph_0$ rationals, yes, but more than $\aleph_0$ irrationals; *at least* $\aleph_1$. (The question of whether it's $\aleph_1$ or something larger is a whole separate issue.)

Comment: MJD, would you like to move this discussion to chat? I'm getting a suggestion on my screen to do that.

Comment: Sorry,  I have to go to bed.

Comment: Ok, well in any case, thanks for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two 'adjacent' real numbers like that. Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were two such numbers, then $\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$ would be between them.

As already pointed out in the comments,
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}n+10^{-t}=n.$$

Comment: Well, now this raises another issue about *cardinality* that I'm considering as a new question

Comment: @jpbrooks-user153707: Ask away!