# How can there be a least upper bound for a set A, that is not itself in A

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

So for the supremum of a set, we say:

$S=sup(A) \Leftarrow \Rightarrow S - \epsilon < x$ for some $x \in S$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

I don't understand this for specific examples where the supremum is not in set A, such as:

$A=\{1-1/n:n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Here the supremum would be $S = 1$, but if $\epsilon = 0.00000... 0001$, it would be greater than 0, but $S - \epsilon \not < x$ for some $x \in S$ (They would be the same).

Comment: There isn't any real number  that behaves like your $\epsilon$. If there were, what would $\frac \epsilon{10}$ be?  What would $10\epsilon$ be?  [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/985069/25554) discusses your $\epsilon$ in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of $sup(A)$ is not quite right.

$S = sup(A) \iff \forall \epsilon > 0 ~\exists x ~\in ~A ~\text{such that}~ (S - \epsilon) < x.$

This means, per the definition of $sup(A)$, 
**first** any (small positive) $\epsilon$ is chosen, 
**then** a *satisfying* $x ~\in A$ must be found.

From the definition of $sup$ that I have given you, you can see that
the example that you offered is not in fact a counter example.

That is, in your example, you offered a small $\epsilon$.
Per the definition of $sup(A)$, **now** an $x ~\in A$ must be selected 
that satisfies **this particular** value of $\epsilon$.

Per the definition of $sup(A)$,
**at no time** must an $x ~\in A$ be found that 
would satisfy **all** possible (small positive) values of $\epsilon.$

Comment: Your definition of $\sup(A)$ is still wrong. What means $x \in S$??

Comment: @J.-E.Pin good catch - thanks.  my blind spot in editing.  Answer corrected.

Comment: You should also remove the symbol $\ni$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Interesting - good suggestion.  Never occurred to me that $\ni$ might not be recognized.  Editing done.

Comment: I think what is confusing me is, why can't $\epsilon = \lim_{x\to \infty} 1/x$, because then there would not exist an $X \in A$ such that $S - \epsilon < x$. So basically, why can't we set $\epsilon$ to the smallest irrational number after 0.

Comment: @RolandKillian "why can't we set $\epsilon$ to the smallest irrational number *after* $0$?" **Answer**: there is no such animal.  That is, for **any** $\epsilon > 0$ that you choose, no matter how small, **after** you choose $\epsilon$, I will simply choose some positive integer $M > \frac{1}{\epsilon}.$  Then, I will have that $\epsilon > \frac{1}{M}.$

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the help!